# Check for variable in class in separate file without knowing class name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am aware of `hasattr()` however I don't think this will work for my specific needs. Here is the situation.

I currently have the ability to check a directory for classes with a specific type. IE `class TabFrame(ttk.Frame)` will be loaded because it inherits specifically from `ttk.Frame`.

I would rather be able to check if any of the classes in the directory contain a class attribute so I can be more specific on what class gets loaded.

The main issue is that I have no way of knowing all the names of the classes in the files in the directory. My current solution creates buttons for each file in the directory rather than the specific class I want to load.

My file that creates all the buttons based on file names in the directory that meet my criteria for valid filenames.

So the issue here is instead of buttons that are created for each valid file name I really need to create buttons for each valid class in each valid file name. I figured I could use a simple class attribute like `self.valid_class = True` as my control for what gets loaded as a button however I do not know how I can validate each class without directly importing them first.

Example code you can use to test how it works:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import os
import glob
import importlib.util as iu
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join

file_list = os.listdir('./ScriptFrames')
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname('.\ScriptFrames\\'), "*.py"))
__all__ = [basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]


class ScriptManager(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tab_list = {}
        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        bot_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.book = ttk.Notebook(bot_frame)
        self.book.pack()
        top_frame.pack()
        bot_frame.pack()
        for ndex, file_name in enumerate([x.split('.')[0] for x in file_list]):
            if not any(substring in file_name for substring in ['__', 'TaskFrame']):
                tk.Button(top_frame, text=file_name, width=30,
                          command=lambda fn=file_name: self.add_tab(fn)).grid(row=ndex, column=0, padx=5, pady=1)

    def add_tab(self, file_name):
        self.process_import(file_name)
        self.add_frame_to_book(self.tab_list[file_name])

    def add_frame_to_book(self, frame_object):
        self.book.add(frame_object, text=frame_object.tab_title)

    def process_import(self, fname=None):
        if fname is not None:
            for fn in __all__:
                if fn == fname:
                    spec = iu.spec_from_file_location('ScriptFrames.{}'.format(fn), '.\ScriptFrames\\{}.py'.format(fn))
                    modlst = iu.module_from_spec(spec)
                    spec.loader.exec_module(modlst)

                    mod_itms = [getattr(modlst, item, None) for item in dir(modlst)]
                    fc = [item for item in mod_itms if isinstance(item, (type,))
                          and issubclass(item, (ttk.Frame, tk.LabelFrame))]

                    self.tab_list[fn] = fc[0]()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScriptManager().mainloop()
```

Base tkinter frame class used from a separate file.
located in a folder in the main directory called ScriptFrames. File name is `TestFrame3` so that is why the button comes up with that name.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class TabFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.valid_tab = "Tab Name" # I want to ID this variable.
        self.tab_title = 'Test Frame 3'
        tk.Label(self, text=self.tab_title).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

How the files are loaded as buttons and then how they load into a tkinter notebook.

**[image: strong text]**

So it works as designed however what I want is to actually check every class in a file and see if that class has a variable that will tell me if I should make a button to open that class in a new tab on the notebook.

Keep in mind I do not know how many files or classes are in this directory but I want to make a button for every valid class as ID'd by whether or not it has the class attribute `self.valid_tab`.

Comment: ***"has the class attribute self.valid_tab"***: That's not possible, a `class attribute` exists only in a instantiated class object and you need a reference. Using a `class variable`, e.g. `class MyClass: VALID = True`, it seems possible.

Comment: @stovfl so I would have to load all the classed into module and test each of the first. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Is this a *one use case*, or does the content of the modules change often?

Comment: @stovfl The idea is to constantly add new classes as I develop new tools. So the first page of the notebook contains all the buttons that will start each little application. Those functions are opened up in the new tab of the notebook to begin work. It works perfectly fine but currently I have to write each new tool into its own file but in a very specific way so my code can ID it. That is why I just want a variable in the class that I can use it ID the actual class that needs to be loaded as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one approach could be to run a "registration" script that writes an `.ini` file after each new commit in the `utils` folder?

The script could inspect each class, parse the values of all classes and their attributes into a set of flags signature that allows to distinguish them, and write into a configuration file, maybe using `configparser`.

You could run it manually, use a tool like `watchdog` to run it every time the folder is modified, or set a `cron` job to run it at intervals.

Upon launching, the GUI, would read (or receive argument from) the latest `.ini` file, and configure itself with the proper buttons.

With this approach, you do not need to import any of the classes prior to needing them; you do not need to validate the classes on the fly; you do not need to worry if your gui reflects the latest additions to `utils`. Further, all the "fugly" inspection of classes, and parsing of the `configuration` file is hidden away in a script that runs only when needed.